# regex for the finding url upto a certain depth/directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am making a list of the browser history in which there are links like 
https://ki.com/Series/To-be-Winner and 
https://ki.com/Series/My-Company-s-Small-/Vol--001-Ch-041?id=664156

I need only the first types of link. I am new to python so i don't know how to use regex in this case.
the code i am using

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("history.csv")
letters = df.url.to_list()
s=list(set(letters))
for i in s:
    if i.startswith("https://ki.com/Series"):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
https://ki\.com/Series/[^?#/]+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/xOpPch/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  https://ki               'https://ki'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  com/Series/              'com/Series/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^?#/]+                  any character except: '?', '#', '/' (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

[Python code](https://tio.run/##dY2xDoIwFEX3fsWLDkDkUYjKYEIcnJ00OigmKjW8CG3zWhP5ekQXXbzjSe45tvO10dO@p9Ya9sBKOCjgENTeW7eQ8k7J1bRyo5iUk@sOV6a1Z92hw017bhqUO9MgpmmGqxrTWbakqsjzWTbPgxj@aLYGLwr3pLXioBQPbj7RUtwMAwFpcAsBw3jArJIb6WpohTz6@o6/wsNpOZblZBQDRZ/jW5mop1e6CjkSlkn78A2jvn8B):

```
urls = []
for i in s:
    r = re.findall(r"https://ki\.com/Series/[^?#/]+", i)
    urls.extend(r)
print(urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're desired pattern is not clear for me but this regex can match with your first URL and ignores second one:

`^https://ki\.com/Series/[^\/]*$`

Comment: the desired pattern is up-to the next "/" or "?" will try this